# Move video forward/backward in Quick Time Player PiP mode

Tags: macbook-pro, video, quicktime, apple-silicon

I am loving Quick Time Player. Why?

I use to watch a lot of video tutorials which I have to follow.

I just add one video and drag & drop the remaining to get a long video; I just love it.

Then, I switch to PiP mode, and the best thing is It also works on fullscreen apps, nice!

But, while in PiP mode, I am not able to use playback controls to forward/backwards the video.

Not even able to pause the video either.

***Is it possible to enable playback controls in PiP mode, or to enable the seek bar to show?***

Answer (score 1):

Use the provided shortcuts like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> to control the Quicktime Player; it also works in PIP mode. I was facing the same issue and just found out that command left/right works perfectly.

Source: [Keyboard shortcuts and gestures in QuickTime Player on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/quicktime-player/qtpa4808515d/mac)